# How to check the URL of a WebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a Subview that load a Webview. In this Webview I load a file HTML locally in the Documents folder of my App. I need to check if the webview load another HTML file. Specifically:

1. Webview load "index.html" locally in my Documents folder
2. After 7 days a Javascript load another page with `location.href= "index2.html"`,
3. When I load this WebView I need to check if the current URL is index.html or index2.html, if is the second I must change Subview!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *currentUrl = [[[yourWebView request] URL] absoluteString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `NSURL` method `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"some/path/to/your/file" isDirectory:NO]` and pass that to a `NSURLRequest` which is then passed to your `UIWebView`. You can get the path to your resource by using the `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource...]` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = myWebView.request.URL;
```